# Copying files from one directory, and sub-directories, to another, so long as sub-directory names match

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm fairly new working in python, I'm making the change from Excel to python, so my reference points tend to be in excel. I'm working out of python 2.7. I understand how to copy files, and how to iterate through a folder copying all the files I need to a specific destination. What I am trying to do, however is a bit more complicated.

Here's the setup:
2 directories: 2017 and 2018
300+ folders in both

What I'm trying to do:
Copy the files (shapefiles, .csv, etc.) from the individual folder in the directory 2017 to the folder of the same name (IF it exists, it may not, and that's okay) in the directory 2018.

I know I need a for loop, and an if statement, I just don't know how to write it:
If folder 'x' exists in both directories 2017 and 2018, copy files 'y_2017' from folder 'x' in 2017 to folder 'x' in 2018.

I'm sure I described this in a poor manner and a rather convoluted way. If anyone has any advice, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: If you think that the answer is correct, please, accept it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

source_folder = "2017"
target_folder = "2018"
subfolders = [a for a in os.listdir(source_folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(source_folder, a))]

for subfolder in subfolders:
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(target_folder, subfolder) and os.path.isdir(os.path.join(target_folder, subfolder)):
        file_names = os.listdir(os.path.join(source_folder, subfolder))
        for f in file_names:
            src_path = os.path.join(source_folder, subfolder, f)
            tgt_path = os.path.join(target_folder, subfolder, f)
            shutil.copy(src_path, tgt_path)
```